# "CDK deploy" doesn't start

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Hi everyone I'm pretty new in AWS CDK and wanted to create a simple app (javaScript) with AWS developer guide :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/hello_world.html

it seems like everything is work fine but when I'm trying to run "cdk deploy" command the deploy is not even starting and is stack in this stage:
[image]

does somebody know what I'm doing wrong or how to get the actual error?

Comment: (1) Don't post pictures, instead post the actual console output within code tags. (2) Are you able to successfully `cdk synth`? (3) Have you looked at CloudFormation in the Console to see if the stack is being created? (4) Do you have any sort of firewall that would block access from your PC to AWS?

Comment: (2) Yes, the "cdk synth" is successful and looks like the example on the guide. (3) on the CloudFormation the stack was created. (4) I don't think that I have a firewall that blocks the access to AWS, I'm trying to deploy while the firewall is disabled and it still not working.

Comment: Did the CloudFormation stack complete? If yes, then it's possible that you don't have the permissions to retrieve stack status. If the stack is failing, look at the events and update your question with the status from the _oldest_ failed event, which will be the root cause of the failure.

Comment: Can you please paste the output when running the deploy with "--verbose"?

Comment: Hi, I running "cdk deploy -vv" and it looks like it's stuck here: [AWS cloudformation 200 0.398s 0 retries] describeStacks({ StackName: 'CDKToolkit' })
Stack CDKToolkit has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS (User Initiated))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using -vvv and --debug options will help you identify the potential issues.

Comment: I think you mean `cdk deploy --verbose`?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to go into my `package.json` file and remove the `bin` node. So I changed this...

```
{
  "name": "cdk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "bin": {
    "cdk": "bin/cdk.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && npx cdk synth",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
    "aws-cdk": "2.55.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.55.1",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```

To this...

```
{
  "name": "cdk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && npx cdk synth",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "10.17.27",
    "@types/prettier": "2.6.0",
    "aws-cdk": "2.55.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-cdk-lib": "2.55.1",
    "constructs": "^10.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
  }
}
```